# Importing strings in Mathematica

Tags: string-manipulation

This is my first post so apologies if any obvious mistakes.

I'm trying to work on a data containing names (in quotes) in *Mathematica*. The data is already saved on my system under `names.txt`. I would like to be able to sort these names in alphabetical order but I can't seem to do anything with it in *Mathematica*. None of the commands seem to be working and the file itself is not recognized as a string. I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake in my code but would greatly appreciate any help. Here's my code below:

Original file (reduced version-original file has more than 1000 names): "MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL","RUTH","SHARON"

```
data1 = {Import["/Users/Joeblogs/Documents/mathematica/names.txt","string"]}
```

the output looks like:

```
{"JOHN", "DAVID", "VIVIAN", "ROBERT"}
```

How do I sort these in alphabetical order?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you use `"String"`?

Comment: Do you mean String (with the "s" in capital)?. I tried that, it's still the same. When I use the "Sort" function, there's no change to the imported data. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: To sort you can use: `Sort[{"JOHN", "DAVID", "VIVIAN", "ROBERT"}]`

Comment: Thanks ruebenko. I've tried this, it just gives the same output as the imported data. I think the main problem is that mathematica is not recognizing the list of names as a string. The names do not go grey like it usually does when you type a word in quotes. Make sense?

Comment: Anything strange when you try `data1//FullForm` ?

Comment: I think that you are importing the entire contents of the file as a single string. Could you please give the exact contents of the file as part of the question, to remove that ambiguity?

Comment: Thanks. This is the output after typing data1//FullForm List["\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\""]

Comment: does that work: `data1 = StringSplit[StringReplace[Import["names.txt"], "\"" -> ""], 
  ","]`? (and then `Sort`)

Comment: @ Pinguin Dirk, Your code worked like magic! Brilliant! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @John so, it seems I was right--you are importing the whole lot as a single string. Import as `"CSV"` instead of `"String"` and the correct result will be obtained.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `ReadList` here instead of `Import` as it gives you lower level control. For the sake of the demo, I converted your example to a string, and using `StringToStream` converted it to an `InputStream`. In actuality, you can use `ReadList` directly on the filename.

```
strm = StringToStream[
  "\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\",\"ELIZABETH\", \
  "\JENNIFER\",\"MARIA\",\"SUSAN\",\"MARGARET\",\"DOROTHY\",\"LISA\", \
  "\NANCY\",\"KAREN\",\"BETTY\",\"HELEN\",\"SANDRA\",\"DONNA\",\"CAROL\", \
  \"RUTH\",\"SHARON\""
]
```

The key is to set the separators in `ReadList`, so it can do the processing for you:

```
ReadList[strm, Word, WordSeparators -> {" ", ",", "\t"}]
```

which returns

```
{"\"MARY\"", "\"PATRICIA\"", "\"LINDA\"", "\"BARBARA\"", 
 "\"ELIZABETH\"", "\"JENNIFER\"", "\"MARIA\"", "\"SUSAN\"", "\"MARGARET\"", 
 "\"DOROTHY\"", "\"LISA\"", "\"NANCY\"", "\"KAREN\"", "\"BETTY\"", 
 "\"HELEN\"", "\"SANDRA\"", "\"DONNA\"", "\"CAROL\"", "\"RUTH\"", 
 "\"SHARON\""}

Close[strm]
```

In your case, replace `strm` with the filename.

Comment: thank you rcollyer, your code works very well and it gives the output in string format. Brilliant! Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: @John `ReadList` is my usual default for this type of thing. Occasionally, I will use `Import`, but quite often I deal with formats that aren't supported by it, although I have written my own filters for it before. However, for simple things, I tend not to bother.